# How to know which process is reading removed farm solution for system.io.filenot found exception in share point 2010

Tags: 2010, farm-solution, error-handling, third-party-software

we have two sharepoint 2010 web front end servers and before deployed a custom farm solution from third party and uninstalled the solution but we saw below errors many times in event viewer .

i don't know which process is still accessing this dll and how to know this and remove this error?

> An error occurred while reading extension file C:\Program
>   Files\xxxxxxxxLibrary.dll.  System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The
>   system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070002)    at System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoadFile(String path,
>   Evidence evidence)    at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(String
>   path)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlRemoteBlobs.ProviderClass.Initialize()